# no matching function for call to 'replace(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, char, int)'|

Tags: c++, replace

How can I change all `\` to `\\`?

I want to make address to work with files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "C:\\user\\asd";
    replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '\\', '\\\\');
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error:

> F:\c++\tests\regex\main.cpp|8|error: no matching function for call to 'replace(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, char, int)'|

How can I do this work with a `char` array in C++ (without a function)?

Comment: `'\\\\'` is a multibyte character and can't be represented by `char`. `'\\\\'` is different from `"\\"`.

Comment: Your question asks about changing / to // but your code uses \ and \\.

Comment: thanks, what to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`std::replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace), which replaces values within a range of iterators.  In this situation, you are using iterators from a `std::string`, so the value being searched for, and the value to replace it with, must both be single `char` values.  However, `'\\\\'` is a multi-byte character, and thus can't be used as a `char` value.  That is why you are getting the compiler error.

`std::string` has its own overloaded [`replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) methods, several of which can replace portions of the `std::string` with multi-character strings.

Try this instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "C:\\user\\asd";

    string::size_type pos = 0;    
    while ((pos = str.find('\\', pos)) != string::npos)
    {
        str.replace(pos, 1, "\\\\");
        pos += 2;
    }

    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/Dj7fih)

However, you say you "want to make address to work with files", which implies  to me that you want to create a [`file:` URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).  If so, then you need something more like this instead (this is a gross over-simplification, a *proper* URI generator would be more complex then this, as [URIs have many rules to them](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), but this will get you started):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const char* safe_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/";

int main()
{
    string str = "C:\\user\\ali baba";

    replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '\\', '/');

    string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ((pos = str.find_first_not_of(safe_chars, pos)) != string::npos)
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << '%' << hex << noshowbase << uppercase << (int) str[pos];
        string newvalue = oss.str();
        str.replace(pos, 1, newvalue);
        pos += newvalue.size();
    }

    str = "file:///" + str;

    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/QdKdG7)

Comment: not to replace all occurrences of a substring with another substring, no.